# Inverse fast fourier transform algorithm on Android

Tags: android, audio

I use AudioRecord on Android to record audio,read into the buffer and use FFT algorithm to transform to frequencies blocks.Now Can I use inverse FFT algorithm to recover the data and playback the sound i have recorded?

Comment: I don't see why this is tagged android, but that sounds about right. Refer to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) on the matter. In particular, see the [Fourier inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem).

Comment: Yes, but caution: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/when-to-not-use-fft.html